# Numerical Triple integral where is the mistake?

Tags: matlab, integral

I am trying to perform a numerical triple integral over `s`, `gamma1`, `gamma2`. The limits are `(-inf +int)`, `(0,+inf)` and `(gamma1,+inf)` respectively. Please dont be scared from the shape of my function (its just a function of `gamma1`, `gamma2`, `s`)

The following is my code

```
syms s
syms gamma1
syms gamma2

fun=-(exp(-(28035689158432973*pi*gamma2^(2/3))/2305843009213693952)*
exp(-(pi*s*7120816246010697*i)/112589990684262400)*
(1/((pi*s*(4194304/gamma1^2 + 4194304/gamma2^2)*i)/(50*
(6144/gamma1 + 6144/gamma2)) + 1)^((3*(2048/gamma1 + 2048/gamma2)^2)
/(4194304/gamma1^2 + 4194304/gamma2^2)) - 1)
*(exp(-(pi^2*s*(log((-(gamma2*25*i)/(1024*pi*s))^(1/3) + 1)/3;


y=@(s,gamma1,gamma2)fun;
gamma2min=@(s,gamma1) gamma1;
prob=integral3(y,-inf,+inf,0,+inf,gamma2min,+inf)
```

I get the following error

```
Error using integralCalc/finalInputChecks (line 511)
Input function must return 'double' or 'single' values. Found 'sym'.
```

Any advice?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `integral3` requires numeric formulas while you are defining it symbolically.  If you read the documentation of `integral3`, it says it **numerically** calculates the integral.  What you'll have to do is use `int` three times - one for each variable.  Check this link out for more details: http://www.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/tripleint.html

Comment: But i do want to evaluate numerically this is what I want to do ? this is why I defined function handle

Comment: You have to define a grid of points that are numerical for you to use `integral3`.  `integral3` finds the approximation to the integral using numerical integration.   You can't use symbolic formulas for `integral3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`quadgk`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quad2d.html) to numerically integrate functions defined like

```
y=@(a,b,c) 1/abs(a^2+b^2+c^2+1);
```

(which I used to test my answer).

It's tricky because `quadgk` expects a function that takes vector input and returns a vector of function values, but you can get around it by using a lot of `arrayfun`'s:

```
R=@(s,gamma1) quadgk(@(gamma2) arrayfun(@(k) y(s,gamma1,k),gamma2),gamma1,Inf)
S=@(s) quadgk(@(gamma1) arrayfun(@(k) R(s,k),gamma1),0,Inf)
T=quadgk(@(s) arrayfun(@(k) S(k),s),-Inf,Inf)
```

But! It's very slow, I wasn't patient enough to wait for the answer. So, replace the `Inf` and `-Inf` limits with 100 and -100, for example, and you will get an answer. Maybe try with 50 and -50 and see how much the solution changes by, if it changes very little then you can be confident the answer is quite accurate, otherwise you'll have to increase the number and wait longer! The faster your function decays the smaller the bounds you will be ale to get away with.

Comment: R=@(s,gamma1) quadgk(@(gamma2) arrayfun(@(k) y(s,gamma1,k),gamma2),gamma1,Inf) Does this line of code mean that we can numerically integrate over gamma2, while keeping s and gamma1 variables ? @David

Comment: @George yes, this is the value of the inner integral for a particular `s` and `gamma1`.